# Flatten 3D VectorA so it's perpendicular to VectorB

Tags: vectors, 3d

Basically I have 2 3D vectors: Vector A (green) and vector B(red).

[image]

I need to calculate a third vector that is perpendicular to VectorA (green) but points in the same direction than VectorB (red). Kinda like "flattening" VectorB.

Please ask me any question to clarify or edit the question if you got it and can make it more clear, I'm completely new to 3d vectors.

EDIT

Here's another example, I added a plane perpendicular to VectorA (the white area). The resulting vector should be in that plane.

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify "perpendicular to $A$ but points in the same direction as $B$"? Orthogonality of vectors is fully determined by their direction, so if $B\not\bot A$, then you have no solution.

Comment: hi @Milly, basically the green vector points to the ground/the direction of the gravity and the red vector is a force applied to an object on the ground. So the direction the object moves will be perpendicular to the green vector. Is that more clear?

Comment: You mean the vector should be in the same plane as VectorA and VectorB and perpendicular to VectorA?

Comment: What is the connection to VectorB then? It is not in the plane. How the resulting vector will point in the same direction as VectorB?

Comment: yes, basically the resulting vector's should be perpendicular to VectorA and if you made a line from it's end and VectorB's end it should be parallel to VectorA.

Comment: It should point in the same direction of VectorB but it should disregard it's movement along the length of vectorA. Basically I'm applying the force to an object on the ground, so no matter how strong it pushes it towards the ground it will only move perpendicular to the gravity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are talking about is called [vector projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection).  In order to project b from a, you could use the formula:
$$ b' = b - {b \cdot a \over a \cdot a} a $$
This can be thought of as the part of b travelling perpendicular to a.